# Atmel Studio: undefined reference to `_read'

Tags: c++, linker-errors, atmelstudio

I started receiving the following Linker error with Atmel Studio:

```
c:/program files (x86)/atmel/studio/7.0/toolchain/arm/arm-gnu-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m\libc.a(lib_a-readr.o): 
In function `_read_r':
    C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\myproj\Debug\readr.c(1,1): error: undefined reference to `_read'
```

This happened after I added a `virtual` method to my project. What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer originally pulled from [this site](https://community.particle.io/t/compiler-linker-fail-virtual-destructors/1320/2).

What's going on is that a built-in `__cxa_pure_virtual` defaults to using `_read` and `_write` via `printf`. To fix, explicitly define that handler to do something else.

```
extern "C" void __cxa_pure_virtual();
extern "C" void __cxa_pure_virtual() { 
    // Add custom handler here
    while(1); 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case, this issue was related to the linker settings of the project configuration.

By setting the linker settings "Additional Specs" to "**Use syscall stubs (--specs=nosys.specs)**", empty syscall implementations for posix system calls like read and write are provided.

These settings are located under

```
Project Properties -> Toolchain -> ARM/GNU Linker -> General -> Additional Specs
```

Comment: This works perfectly for me and seems preferable to me compared to the accepted answer. Less work and less breackage from libraries.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I traced it to an issue with the asf defining assert() to something invalid when 'NDEBUG' is not defined in the project compile\link symbols.

Specifically,

- Project properties->Toolchain->ARM\GNU C Compiler->Symbols: Add NDEBUG as a -D 'defined symbol'.
- Project properties->Toolchain->ARM\GNU Preprocessing Assembler->Symbols: Add NDEBUG as a -D 'defined symbol'.